# Does Spring Security Oauth2 Client refreshes the token everytime we hit the client api or it only refreshes when token is expired?

Tags: spring-security

I want to understand how spring Oauth2 client manages the token.
The bearer token is it automatically refreshes the token on expiry or It generates new token on every api call?

Comment: What client library do you use?I guess not the end of life library for Spring Security 4.